# What 's' represents in cells in this dataset?

Tags: statistics, dataset, bigdata, data-science

I need to use this public dataset:
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2015-2016-demographic-data-grades-k-8-school

You can view data in this table viewer:
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Education/2015-2016-Demographic-Data-Grades-K-8-School/7yc5-fec2

Many cells have `No data` in them, which is clear for me. However many others have `s` which is unclear. I didn't find any explanation.

I guess maybe it is some standard way of telling why data is absent in that cell. Or maybe not and only authors of data know it.

Please tell me what `s` mean or may mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "universal" meaning behind this.
It could be a number of things:

- Data not present
- Not applicable
- Use case specific information
- Error in the dataset itself
- ...

If you want to create value out of this data, don't make assumptions, look for documentation or description of dataset, which describes its columns, types and expected content. The owner or creator of this dataset should of course also be able to inform you of what it represents.